# Python / Pulp - first pick one item of each group

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
City      Country      Time      Points
---------------------------------------
London    UK            31         20
Paris     France        42         12
Sydney    Australia     73         44
New York  US            41         18
Lyon      France        22         25
...
...
```

Program should pick cities to visit in given time frame. There is only a time constraint and no strict constraint in number of cities.

However:

- each city should be visited once at maximum
- you can visit twice in the same country, but only after you have visited in every single country in the dataframe. (same goes for the 3rd time in the same country: you have to visit each country twice before)

Currently my code looks like this:

```
max_time = 500

x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", df.index, 0, 1, pulp.LpInteger)
mod = pulp.LpProblem("travel_prog", pulp.LpMaximize)

objval_points = {idx: (df['Points'][idx]) for idx in df.index}
mod += sum([x[idx]*objval_points[idx] for idx in df.index])

objval_time = {idx: (df['Time'][idx]) for idx in df.index}
mod += sum([x[idx]*objval_time[idx] for idx in df.index]) < max_time

for idx in df.index:    
    mod += x[idx] <= 1
```

I have created a constraint that allows the program to choose only one city per country, but this is not what i want:

```
for country in df['Country'].unique():
    sub_idx = df[df['Country']==country].index
    mod += pulp.lpSum([x[idx] for idx in sub_idx]) <= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of times each country is visited. Put this in a variable say `CountVisit[Country]`. Introduce variable `maxVisit` and `MinVisit`. Then add constraints `maxVisit >= CountVisit[Country]` and `MinVisit <= CountVisit[Country]` and finally impose the constraint `MaxVisit-MinVisit<=1`.